# Не получается сделать отправку формы с файлом на почту

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Не могу сделать, что бы сообщение с сайта отправлялось с прикрепленным файлом. Текстовые поля отправляются, но файл не передается. Буду рад любой помощи!

```js
$('#form-vacancii').submit(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  const form = $(this);

  let formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  let msgArea = $(form).find('.form-result');
  //formData = $(form).serialize(),
  url = '/obrabotchik-formy-vakansii.php';

  $(form).find('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], textarea').removeClass('error');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function() {

      $(msgArea).html('<span>' + response + '</span>');

    }

  })
  $("#form-vacancii").trigger('reset');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--ФОРМА-->
<form id="form-vacancii" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="input-container">
    <div style="width:295px;">
      <label>Имя*</label>
      <input name="yourName" style="margin-right:20px;" class="vacansii-input" placeholder="Представьтесь,пожалуйста" required>
    </div>
    <div style="width:295px;">
      <label>Email*</label>
      <input class="vacansii-input" name="email" placeholder="Введите,ваш email" required>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="input-container">
    <div style="width:295px;">
      <label>Телефон*</label>
      <input id="mask-phone" name="tel" style="margin-right:20px;" class="vacansii-input" placeholder="+7 (999) 999-99-99">
    </div>
    <div style="width:295px;">
      <label>Какая вакансия Вас интересует?</label>
      <select name="select" style="" class="vacansii-input" placeholder="">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vacansii-input-file" style="margin-top:20px;"><label style="display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;">
    <img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:60px;height:60px;" src="https://thecbd.ru/upload/medialibrary/f31/n7ptf7dj1ln1rjd4i9v9a5r7jqn73u4d/Group (7).png" alt="Нажмите для выбора файла.">
            <br><span>Прикрепите резюме</span>
<input   id="resume" name="resumе" style="" type="file" >
    </label>
  </div>

  <button class="form-button btn btn-dark w-100 subscribebutton" name="web_form_submit" value="Подписаться">Отправить</button>
  <span>* - обязательные поля</span>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Обработчик формы вакансии");
?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
?>
<?


header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arEventFields=array(
    
"USER_NAME"=>$_POST['yourName'], 
"USER_TEL"=>$_POST['tel'],
"USER_EMAIL"=>$_POST['email'],
"USER_PROFI"=>$_POST['select'],
"RESUME"=>$_FILES['resume'],
);

CEvent::Send("RESUME", "s1", $arEventFields,"N","","");

?>
```

Comment: Почитай мануал https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cevent/send.php